# Switch statement assistance?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I am writing a problem that prompts the user to enter a color (red, blue, yellow, purple & white) & quantity, which will output a flower in the following output: You have [quantity] [type of flower]. Each color has to have at least two flowers assigned to them. As the title states, I have to have a switch statement in the program for the variable that initializes the type of flowers assigned to that color. Here is the sample of the switch statement I've written:

```
int quantity;
String color;
String flower;//the type of flower associate with the color

System.out.print("Please enter a color: ");
    color = input.next();
    System.out.print("Please enter the quantity: ");
    quantity = input.nextInt();

    switch(color){
    case red:
        System.out.println("You have one rose.");
        break;
    case blue:
        System.out.println("You have 2 blue irises.");
        break;
```

What am I doing wrong? I feel as if I have to include a possible if-statement as well.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself." What is the specific problem you are encountering?

Comment: I'm basically trying to use a switch statement to allow the program to output a flower based off the quantity/color I enter. I have to deter from using the typical if-/else if- statements.

Comment: Your assignment is not clear. I think you are mixing the requirement for having at least two flowers in the color (which means you have to check the quantity and reject it if it's only 1), and the requirement for printing the result based on the color. These are two separate requirements and should be handled in separate steps.

Answer (score 1):

You look to be on the right track. In your case statements, use the `flower`  variable you defined above. Assign your type of flower for that color. Also, the actual case is a string, so it needs to be in double quotes.

```
switch (color) {
    case "red":
        flower = "rose(s)";
        break;
    case "blue":
        flower = "hydrangea(s)";
        break;
}
```

You can then call your `println` method after your switch statement like this:

```
System.out.println("You have " + quantity + " of " + flower);
```

Comment: How to implement two cases into one, like for the color red, I have to have  at least two flowers assigned to one color?

Comment: I modified the answer. Is that what you are looking for?